# How to have absolute require / import paths to the project root?

Tags: node.js, path, webpack

I want all the paths in my application to be relative to my project root, so that I don't have to do:

```
import foo from "../../bar.js";
var foo = require("../../bar.js");
```

My client side of the application is compiled using Webpack, so I imagine that I can use the 'resolve' facility in the Webpack, but would prefer not to as this adds a dependency to using Webpack. The backend uses an Node/Express server.

Is there a solution that works in both front and back-end?

Comment: do you want to reference a dependency during development from the root ? since webpack creates a monolith bundle, there will be no problems on the client

Comment: Yes, but on both client and server. i.e. in some cases I have files that are used by both client and server and they have dependencies in them with relative paths.

Comment: You could just create a symbolic link to point to your `src` directory and put it inside your `node_modules` directory: `ln -fs ../src node_modules/`. Then you could `require('src/bar')`.

Comment: This is limited to just items in the node_modules folder, what about any other files that I want to import/require from other folders in the root, e.g. /seed, /config, /i18n, /shared... ?

Comment: You could instead create a symbolic link named `root` to point to your project's root directory, and put it under the node_modules directory  or something. Then you could `require('root/seed/bar')`. You'll want to create this symbolic link during your project's `postinstall` npm script.

Comment: I'm not creating an npm package, I'm creating an application with client and server-side elements - how is symoblic linking going to work?

Comment: I assume you have a package.json file, right? And you have some dependencies listed, correct? Then when you run `npm i` from that directory it will install all of your dependencies and run whatever command you have listed in your package.json at `scripts.postinstall`. So you would put whatever command you wanted there to create the symbolic link.

Comment: And this will work for both client and server-side import/require ?

Comment: "this adds a dependency to using Webpack" If that is a problem for you, create an abstraction for it so that you can easily replace underlying bundling system.

Comment: How do you create an abstraction for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your package.json add `ln -fsn ../ 'node_modules/>'` at the following JSON path `scripts.postinstall`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ln -fsn ../ 'node_modules/>'"
  }
}
```

This will create a symbolic link named `>` in your project's `node_modules` which is pointing to your project's root folder.

Assuming your file structure looked like this:

```
project
├── bar.js
├── config
│   ├── database.js
│   ├── rabbitmq.js
│   └── env.js
├── seed
│   ├── soy.js
│   ├── wheat.js
│   ├── pumpkin.js
│   └── squash.js
├── foo
│   └── bar
│       └── baz
│           └── qux.js
├── index.js
└── package.json
```

From inside the `foo/bar/baz/qux.js` file we could require the `seed/soy.js` file like this:

```
require('>/seed/soy')
```

Comment: This works, until you need to install new packages. You get an error with npm, unless I'm missing something. Edit: This is only with Yarn